# csv file parse and upload giving error in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

This is the field on form, I am using

```
<%= f.file_field :file ,:url=>{:controller=>"retailers",:action=>"csv_import"}%>
```

The following is the controller code

```
def create
    @retailer = Retailer.new(params[:retailer])
    respond_to do |format|     
          if verify_recaptcha(:model =>@retailer ) && @retailer .save 

        # To notify newly registered user.
          retailer_ids = [@retailer.id]
          Emailer.on_notify_retailer(retailer_ids, 1, 0)
        sign_in @retailer
        format.html { redirect_to pages_about_path}
        flash[:notice1] = "Thank you for registering with Chindi."
        flash[:notice2] = "We will process your application and get back to you within 48 hours. Once approved, you will be able to create negotiable deals that Consumers can tailor to their needs."
        flash[:notice3] = "You will be able to create, manage and administer your deals and your buyers in this easy to use control panel."

        format.json { render json:  pages_about_path, status: :created, location: @retailer }
        else
        @title = "Sign up"
        format.html { render action: "new"}
    flash[:notice1] = "Incorrect word verification. Are you sure you\'re human?"
        format.json { render json: @retailer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end


     end

    csv_parse()

  end
```

The above code is used to save the data into database. The CSV file `@retailer.file_file_name` is to be stored in database as well as it needs to be parsed and the values need to be stored in fields

1. csv_parse is used to parse the csvfile
2. I am able to save file in data

now i need to parse the csv file and store the individual fields in another database.

the code for csv_parse is as follows.

```
   def csv_parse 

     @parsed_file=CSV.foreach(params[:dump][:file].original_filename)

     n=0
     @parsed_file.each  do |row|
      User_list.create(
     :email=>row[0],
     :first_name=>row[1],
     :last_name=>row[2]).save

     flash.now[:message]="CSV parse Successful,  #{n} new records added to data base"
   end
end
```

when I run this it gives the following error/s.

1. You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
2. You might have expected an instance of Array.
3. The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

please help me with the above error why is it throwing such an error

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just checking, but have you inspected `params` to confirm that `:dump` and `:dump[:file]` are actually defined?

Comment: @rjz i am completely new to ruby on rails,i am unable to understand what you are trying to say can you please be more specific.Thank you very much.

Comment: @rjz can you please give a detailed information about :dump

Comment: @clyfe :can you please look into this problem and present a possible solution

Comment: `params` is the variable containing everything that was posted from your view. My guess is that the error is happening when you try to assign to `@parsed_file`. If you call `abort params.inspect` before trying to set the variable, you should be able to check whether the key you're asking for (`:dump`) exists and  contains a `:file` field.

Comment: @Tass, sorry i didn't get you..

Comment: [google helps](https://www.google.ch/search?q=ruby+full+backtrace)

Answer (score 0):

I just paste some peace of working for me code and hope it will help you:

```
first_line = true
file = File.open File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp/import/category.csv')
file.each do |line|
  unless first_line
    row = CSV::parse_line(line, ';')
    category = Category.find_by_name(row[1]) || Category.create(:name => row[1], :target => 'basic')
    category.update_attribute(:import_id, row[0])
  else
    first_line = false
  end
end
```

I sometime wrote this code to import categories to my DB. Here you can change CSV file name and block for `each` iterator. Also `first_line` is description for fields and I was ignoring it.

Comment: i have already achieved uploading file now i need to parse it.

Comment: ok thank you very much for the reply and now i will explain what exactly i am trying to do.As you can see there is a variable "@retailer" in "create" he holds many fields inside him one of which is path to the csv file and it is saved in a db whose column name is file_file_name.now how do i extract the path from variable "@retailer" and how do i pass it to your function,please reply soon i need to get this finished and thank you very much for your prompt replies once again.

Comment: I don't see any problem - replace string 'tmp/import/category.csv' with value from your field in DB `file_file_name`

Comment: i am getting the following error. "No such file or directory - /home/chindi/db/import/users_list.csv"

Comment: file = File.open(@retailer.file_file_name) ?

Comment: when i am using this, i am getting an error, file_file_name is of type BLOB

Comment: when am using this.... def import
   import_file = File.read(@retailer.file)
 CSV.parse(import_file.read).each do |row|
      temp_user = UserList.new(:email => row[0], :first_name => row[1], :last_name => row[2])
      unless temp_user.save
         temp_user.is_valid = false
         temp_user.save(false)
      end
   end
end                                                                  i get the following error.. "can't convert Paperclip::Attachment into String"

Comment: when i am using this...... def import
   import_file = File.open(@retailer.file_file_name)
 CSV.parse(import_file.read).each do |row|
      temp_user = UserList.new(:email => row[0], :first_name => row[1], :last_name => row[2])
      unless temp_user.save
         temp_user.is_valid = false
         temp_user.save(false)
      end
   end
end                                                                   i get the following error.. " CSV::MalformedCSVError"

Comment: Do you see difference between my code and your? I' going through each file line and trying parse THIS EACH LINE as CSV, but you are using ANOTHER METHOD: CSV.parse

Comment: what is the difference between the two can u please tell

Comment: Parse each line of file, but not all CVS file. You are trying to parse entire file and it has error and it fails that's why. I think you also will have problems with parsing each line because this CSV is not valid, but if you parse each line you will know which exactly line is wrong and will not what is wrong

Comment: when i use this i got the following error... CSV::MalformedCSVError

Comment: when i am using your method i am getting the following error CSV::MalformedCSVError any guesses why this is happening?

Comment: It seems that your CSV is not valid. I had the same exception when my column was containing quote symbol. It was **"** for me

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @retailer = Retailer.new(params[:retailer])
  respond_to do |format|     
    # ... same as above
  end
  csv_parse(params[:retailer][:file].path)

  private

  def csv_parse(path)
    rows = CSV.read(path)
    rows.each do |row|
      User_list.create(:email=> row[0], :first_name=>row[1], :last_name=>row[2])
    end
    flash.now[:message]= "CSV parse Successful, #{rows.size} new records added"
  end
end
```